# Create a Google Datastore Index for a Excluded Value

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I need to create a Datastore index for a string field.

The problem is that the property explicitly uses the `setExcludeFromIndexes(true)`

Index got created but is empty.

How can I for the index to build ignoring this `ExcludeFromIndexes`?

Answer (score 0):

From https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#unindexed_properties: "Note: If a property appears in a composite index, then excluding the property will disable it in the composite index. "

You'll need to index the properties for both build-in & composite indexes, i.e. change your entities to include the wanted property in indexes.